# Ctrl-z doesn't work in vi launched from Gnome terminal

Tags: terminal, kill, vi

I'm trying to switch Vi launched from Fedora Gnome terminal to background and go back to bash with Ctrl-Z but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> only suspends Vim [in certain modes](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#CTRL-Z). In other modes, it is not treated specially.

It is also possible that someone has [disabled job control in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137915/disabling-job-control-in-bash-ctrl-z) for your terminal.

`vi` has many other ways to do things via the shell while the editor runs. Some examples:

1. **Drop me to a command shell:**

   ```
   :sh
   ```

   To get back to `vi`, say `exit`, not `fg` as you would when you get out of `vi` via <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>.
2. **Run a single command in the shell:**

   ```
   :!some-command
   ```
3. **Start a `make(1)` run:** From Vim or Elvis, you can say

   ```
   :make [target]
   ```

   ...instead of `:!make [target]`
4. **Read the output of a command into the current buffer:**

   ```
   :r !some-command
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it in different Vi modes - no effect and also checked job control you mentioned, doesn't help either. The only thing that seems to work is :stop which is the equivalent of Ctrl-Z in Vi.

Comment: @kirill_l: What version of Fedora is this, and what language and keyboard settings did you choose when setting the OS up? Also, does Ctrl-Z work in other programs such as `nano`?

Comment: Warren, thanks for your help. I don't have enough points on this particular SE site to upvote your answer so instead I marked it as "best"

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. I'm running Fedora in VirtualBox where, as it turned out, the right Ctrl key is by default reserved for "host" actions i.e. any right Ctrl combinations are intercepted by VB itself. The left Ctrl key combinations including Ctrl-Z are working fine.

Comment: This is the first time I have known *anyone* to use the right Ctrl key, particularly for the most common shortcuts, which were purposely chosen because the pairs are under a handspan apart: Ctrl-A, Ctrl-S, Ctrl-Z, Ctrl-X, Ctrl-C, and Ctrl-V. On the Mac, add Cmd-Q, Cmd-W, and Cmd-D. This is why some of these shortcuts have strange mnemonics: Z and V don't say "undo" and 
"paste" to me, and X as an alias for "cut" is a stretch. These shortcuts had to have these letters because they're the *available* letters near Ctrl on a US Qwerty keyboard. Thus why VirtualBox felt free to use right-Ctrl.